# Raspberry Pi 4B: AP and Client

Tags: wifi, ethernet, bridge

I ran [this](https://www.willhaley.com/blog/raspberry-pi-wifi-ethernet-bridge/) tutorial to setup my Raspberry Pi 4B as a WiFi-to-Eth Bridge, then ran [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gdtkHZtfsbw) tutorial to add a virtual access point to allow me to SSH in afterwards. So far the bridge works and I can see the extra WiFi network on my iPhone when scanning. Problem is I can't connect to this new network, however, the 'loading' circle continues to spin on my iPhone but I'm never actually successfully connected. Does anyone with some networking experience know what's going wrong or how to diagnose the issue? I've attached my 'ifconfig' output on the Pi and my iPhone's automatically obtained IP Address.

I'm guessing part of the problem is the difference in subnet between the iPhone and the Pi, but not sure what else to do beyond that. Thanks!

[image]

[image]